# display multiple value of same column in mysqli php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display value in checkbox. i have multiple value in database as shown in pic above. please have a look. I want value in different checkbox not in same checkbox

[image: How its looking now[![My table.[![Expected result]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP0Pe.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wiFM.png)

Code I am trying

```
<div class="list-group">
            <h3>Name</h3>
            <?php 
                $query = "select distinct(name) from info_user where user_status = '1'";  
                $rs = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error());
                while($color_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){

            ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="item_filter colour" value="<?php echo $color_data['name']; ?>"  >
                &nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $color_data['name']; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>  
            </div>
```

and what i tried by myself

```
  <div class="list-group">
            <h3>Name</h3>
            <?php 
                $column = array();
                $query = "select name from info_user where user_status = '1'";  
                $rs = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error());
                while($color_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
                    $column[] = $color_data['name'];


            ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="item_filter colour" value="<?php foreach($column as $value)echo $value['name']; ?>"  >
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <?php foreach($column as $value)echo $value['name']; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>  
            </div>
```

Getting this error after trying code

[image: Getting error after my putting new code in page]

Comment: what is the current output ??

Comment: hey @MayankMajithya after trying myself I am getting this error [this is current error](https://i.imgur.com/lqn6E2p.png) and what is expected  [what i am looking for](https://i.imgur.com/pcLP7vD.png)

Comment: In your second example "what i tried by myself" you should just use `$value`, not `$value['name']` as you already used the `'name'` index on `$color_data` when you assigned the values to `$column`.

Comment: hey @Nick I did correction as you mention [this showing](https://i.imgur.com/cMBRIji.png) and I am looking for [this](https://i.imgur.com/pcLP7vD.png)

Comment: So does the table have entries which look like "bhavesh,ashwin"?

Comment: [I have database like this](https://i.imgur.com/Uz8F865.png) , multiple value in same column

Comment: OK, I think I understand. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
<div class="list-group">
    <h3>Name</h3>
<?php 
$column = array();
$query = "select name from info_user where user_status = '1'";  
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while ($color_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $column = array_merge($column, explode(',', $color_data['name']));
}
$column = array_unique($column);
foreach ($column as $value) {
?>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"> 
        <input type="checkbox" class="item_filter colour" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" >
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $value; ?>
        </a>
<?php } ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: [it looking like this](https://i.imgur.com/0Rl1Ike.png) and I [want like this](https://i.imgur.com/pcLP7vD.png) every value in new checkbox.

Comment: Sorry I had a spurious ?> in the code. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way, update your code

```
<div class="list-group">
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <?php
    $column = array();
    $query = "select distinct(name) from info_user where user_status = '1'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($color_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        $column = array_merge($column, explode(',',$color_data['name']));
    }
    // to remove repeated names  
    $column = array_filter($column);
    ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"> 
        <input type="checkbox" class="item_filter colour" value="<?php
               foreach ($column as $value) {
                   echo $value;
                   ?>">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <?php
            echo $value;
        }
        ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for code. after trying your code it shows this error [click me](https://i.imgur.com/jtb0YYb.png)

Comment: I had update the code, there is small mistake, please check now

Comment: i applied your updated code [click me](https://i.imgur.com/aeZk6nD.png) I tried to debug but couldn't...